# Is there a LINQ statement to enumerate all parents?

Tags: c#, linq, tree

I have a class that contains a reference to a parent object

```
class Joint 
{
    public Joint Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

Given a single `Joint` I can enumerate all the parent objects in the chain with

```
    public IEnumerable<Joint> ThisAndParentJoints
    {
        get
        {
            Joint joint=this;
            while(joint!=null)
            {
                yield return joint;
                joint=joint.Parent;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do the above using a single LINQ statement?

NOTE: I can find all the child joints given a `List<Joint> all`

```
public IEnumerable<Joint> ChildJoints { 
    get { return all.Where((jnt) => jnt.Parent==this); } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although the recursion works the other way in the other post, indeed it answers my question and it is similar enough to be makred as a duplicate.